# Error: The argument type 'MaterialAccentColor' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MaterialColor'

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, program-entry-point

I am writing a basic Flutter app and getting this error for only some specific colors.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' ;
import 'pages/home_page.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
      themeMode : ThemeMode.light,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.orangeAccent
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I assign the primary swatch color to `Colors.orange` or `Colors.red` , It works fine. But when I switch to any accent colors such as `Colors.orangeAccent`, it returns this error.

How do I use a color accent ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign `Colors.orangeAccent` to `primarySwatch` because datatype of `Colors.orangeAccent` is different from what `primarySwatch` is expecting.

You can assign `Colors.orangeAccent` to `accentColor` property of `MaterialApp`.